# How to debug into `MeasureOverride` of a UWP UI control

Tags: debugging, gridview, uwp, uicontrol

I am trying to find out the cells pacing used in the GridView control in UWP. I have tried setting the symbol server to Microsoft server and derived a class from GridView and overridden few virtual method. I was hoping that I would debug into the `MeasureOverride`.

I am using visual studio 2017.

Alternately, if I can look into just the source that is also enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for styling, I'd recommend using the built-in [XAML inspector in Visual Studio 2017](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx). Use it to navigate to your `GridView` and find where the spacing is applied. You'll find that it's going to be a `Style` you have to override where `Padding` or `Margin` are hardcoded.

Comment: This does solve my issue of cellspacing example in the question. However I would still like to know how to debug into the UWP control as I am trying to find out what is happening in the control. cell spacing was just an example.

Comment: I don't think those controls have any source available for you. They are delivered as native libraries. If you figure it out, post it here. I would love to see the source for the built-in controls in UWP.